# SELECT with LEFT JOIN with two tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Both have different values except the email. I select from both tables with a Left join of second table on same email. Unfortunately there a duplicate emails in the first table.

```
+-------+----------+------+
| email | address  | id   |
+-------+----------+------+
|  a    |    a     |  1   |
|  b    |    b     |  2   |
|  c    |    c     |  3   |
|  a    |    d     |  4   |
+-------+----------+------+

+-------+----------+------+
| email | password | etc  |
+-------+----------+------+
|  a    |    a     |  1   |
|  b    |    b     |  2   |
|  c    |    c     |  3   |
|  d    |    d     |  4   |
+-------+----------+------+
```

My goal is to get only distinct rows per email choosing the row with the highest id of table1

So far my Query looks like that:

```
SELECT t2.email, t1.address, t2.city
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t1.email IS NOT NULL
```

How do I get the wanted result without those duplicates?

**Edit**

```
+-------+----------+------------+
| email | address  | password   |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  a    |    a     |     1      |
|  b    |    b     |     2      |
|  c    |    c     |     3      |
|  d    |    d     |     4      |
+-------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Show the results that you want.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from t2 left join
     (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1
     on t1.email = t2.email and t1.seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is a window function that assigns a sequential number to rows with the same email -- with the highest id getting "1" and then incrementing as the `id` decreases.  This identifies the row with the largest id and the `seqnum = 1` retrieves only that row for each `email`.

Comment: could you please explain how this query works? Do not know the rom_number() over and partition terms.

Comment: Did u switch t2 with t1 in the FROM term on purpose? Or is there also a reason for that. I should point out that t1 is way larger than t2.

Comment: @EldoRay . . . You want one row per email.  That seems to be what `t2` has.  Hence, it is the first table in the `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select temp.email, t1.address, t2.password from
  (select max(id) as max_id, email from table1
  group by email) temp 
  Left join table1 t1 on t1.id = temp.max_id
  Left join table2 t2 on t2.email = temp.email
```